# Visual Studio - Подсветка синтаксиса - Цвет полей класса/локальных переменных/аргументов функций/имён свойств/имён методов

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте. Как можно настроит подсветку синтаксиса в редакторе Visual Studio для следующих объектов:

- Имя свойства
- Имя метода
- Поле класса
- Локальная переменная в функции
- Аргумент функций

Знаю про настройки: Сервис -> Параметры -> Окружение -> Шрифты и цвета.
Но в этих настройках не нашёл нужные параметры (нашёл только параметры цвета для класса, делегата, интерфейса и др.)

Answer (score 1):

Расширение для Visual Studio:
[Color Coder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xellarix.ColorCoder)
[image: Пример]